# "On which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

I met the following line: "of listening ears on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales" in the novel *[Waterland](http://www.fiction2.com/waterland-online-graham-swift?page=0,2)*, written by Graham Swift.

> I began, having recognized in my young but by no means carefree class the contagious symptoms of fear: ‘Once upon a time …’
>
> Children, who will inherit the world. Children to whom, throughout history, stories have been told, chiefly but not always at bedtime, in order to quell restless thoughts; whose need of stories is matched only by the need adults have of children to tell stories to, of receptacles for their stock of fairy-tales, of listening ears **on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales, their own lives**; children – they are going to separate you and me. Lewis has seen to it. Forgive this emotion. I do not deserve your protestations. (We need our Cricky and all that stuff of his.) I do not expect you to understand that after thirty-two years I have rolled you all into one and now I know the agonies of a mother robbed of her child.… But listen, listen. Your history teacher wishes to give you the complete and final version …
>
> And since a fairy-tale must have a setting, a setting which, like the settings of all good fairy-tales, must be both palpable and unreal, let me tell you

Below, is the line which has prompted me to ask the following questions.

> "whose need of stories is matched only by the need adults have of children to tell stories to, of receptacles for their stock of fairy-tales, of listening ears **on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales, their own lives**"

1. Does the sentence “... of listening ears on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales ...” mean: "The adult have the need to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales on the listening ears"?
2. Does the word *yet* mean "used for emphasizing that someone or something is even bigger, better, worse, more etc than someone or something else" in *yet haunting of fairy-tales*?
3. Is the word *haunting* an adjective?
4. Does the word *haunting* mean "sad or beautiful in a way that is difficult to forget"
5. Does the word "of" in “haunting of fairy-tales” have the same meaning as the word "of" in the sentence "It is very nice of you to say that"?
6. Does the word "of" in "haunting of fairy-tales" mean "used to indicate that someone has behaved in a specified way"?

Thanks a lot for everyone's help in advance.

Comment: These are a lot of questions instead of a single one. It may help to split up the convoluted sentence you are struggling with into seperate parts to start with: _Adults have a need of children to tell stories to. Adults have a need of receptacles for their stock of fairy-tales. Adults have a need of listening ears on which to unload fairy tales. Adults have a need of listening ears on which to unload their own lives._

Comment: At first sight it seems like a lot of questions, but they all revolve around one particular sentence. The OP has clearly shown effort, and attempted to find an answer to their question.

Comment: @oerkelens   Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A    Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. How can I reopen my question? Thank you so much for your help again.

Comment: The post has been put on hold because some users think you have asked too many questions. I  don't believe you have. Your Q contains context, a clear source, and you have identified the areas which have caused you  difficulty. You have also attempted to answer those problems. So, [visit meta, and ask](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/)  if they believe this question is still off topic after the edit (I edited your post when there were already four votes for closure, so it was a little too late). Ask users to explain how you may improve it. Best of luck, I think you stand a good chance!

Comment: If you do write your request on meta, don't forget to add the link back to this question!

Comment: Should I ask a question in http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/ in order to reopen my question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have already posted a question.  http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/9359/could-you-please-reopen-my-question

Comment: Well done. But I think your request would be better received, if you also asked how you might improve your question. It will show a willingness on your behalf to understand why the question was put on hold.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A What English textbooks did you study in your primary school English courses?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thank you very much for your help. What English textbooks did you study in your secondary school English courses?

Answer (score 3):

> *"whose need of stories is matched only by the need adults have of children to tell stories to, of receptacles for their stock of fairy-tales, of listening ears on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales, their own lives"*

1) *Does the sentence "of listening ears on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales" mean "The adult have the need to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales on the listening ears"?*

**Yes, except we say that "the adults have" or "the adult (singular) has".**

2) *Does the word "yet" mean "used for emphasizing that someone or something is even bigger, better, worse, more etc than someone or something else" in the sentence "of listening ears on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales"?*

***yet* means *but* here, which in turn means "and (surprisingly)".**

3) *Is the word "haunting" an adjective in the sentence "of listening ears on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales"?*

**yes**

4) *Does the word "haunting" mean "sad or beautiful in a way that is difficult to forget" in the sentence "of listening ears on which to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales"?*

**yes**

EDIT:  "Haunting" doesn't mean "sad **or** beautiful" but it could mean "sad **and** beautiful" in this context.  "haunting" (as an adjective) really just means that it's difficult to forget, and that could be for a variety of reasons.

5) *Does the word "of" in "haunting of fairy-tales" have the same meaning as the word "of" in the sentence "It is very nice of you to say that"?*

**The phrase is "the most haunting of fairy-tales" and it means that it is *the most haunting fairy tale*. The meaning of "of" is similar to "belonging to" in this context, and it can be seen as a contraction of "The most haunting tale from the set of all fairy tales".**

6) *Does the word "of" in "haunting of fairy-tales" mean "used to indicate that someone has behaved in a specified way"?*

**No, it means what I said in question 5**

Comment: Pedant point: In the first question, it means "The adults have the need to unload those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales, *their own lives*, on the listening ears". Otherwise there is nowhere left in the sentence to make clear that the fairy-tales are actually true stories.

Comment: @Max Williams Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. Do the word "unbelievable" and the word "haunting" both use their superlative degree in "those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales"? Thank you so much for your help again.

Comment: @Spagirl  Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @LiXiaodong "superlative degree" refers to words ending in "est" such as weakest, strongest etc, and also "most weak", "most strong".  The "most" here, I think, applies only to "unbelievable", but it might apply to "haunting" too.  So I'd say definitely yes for "unbelievable" and "maybe" for "haunting".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. Does "those most unbelievable yet haunting of fairy-tales" mean "those most unbelievable but haunting fairy-tales from the set of all fairy-tales"? Thank you so much for your help again.

Comment: It means, most simply that they are "the most unbelievable and haunting fairy tales in the world" (a more idiomatic way of saying "the set of all fairy tales")

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. What English textbooks did you study in your primary school English courses? Thank you so much for your help again.

Comment: @LiXiaodong I am English myself so we didn't study English textbooks at primary school (we just read books).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. What English books did you read in primary school?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry.  It was a long time ago :)

Comment: Do you study English textbooks in your secondary school English courses?

Comment: @Max Williams  Do you still remember what English books you read in secondary school? Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @LiXiaodong you're barking up the wrong tree I'm afraid, my English knowledge isn't very formal and was mainly learned by reading a huge amount of novels, which I'm not going to list and which aren't in themselves anything special, anyway.

Comment: 'Does the word "haunting" mean "sad or beautiful in a way that is difficult to forget"...Yes'. I disagree entirely Is a supermodel necessarily haunting? Is a dying family member necessarily haunting? No. Also, the online dictionary meanings all seem to miss the connotation of 'like a ghost'. "Giselle Bundchen was the most haunting of ex-girlfriends"... no that just doesn't work.

Comment: @Mitch that's what it means **in this context**.

Comment: @MaxWilliams 'sad _and_ beautiful' maybe. 'Haunting' never means 'sad _or_ beautiful...'

Comment: @mitch - you're right, i misread it as "and", thanks.  I'll edit my answer.